# Gmail threading is not retained for certain users, which is resulting in stray/single replies. How to stop it?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, email-forwarding, email-headers

We have a domain based on Gmail. This question is for the within domain users.
Whenever a certain user replies to my email, it mostly creates a new thread of its own. For example, if I start an email chain with

> subject: Hello World

Now, if this specific user replies to the email, then it mostly creates following new chain with the previous body inlined:

> subject: Re: Hello World

My expectation is that the email should have remained clubbed as it happens for all the other users. BTW, this behaviour is consistent. Sometimes it happens after certain email replies.
In my Gmail > Settings > General > Conversation view is ON.

How to prevent this unwanted individual replies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the root cause, probably!

That email chain breaking was happening, when that particular person was sending me email from their Macbook by popping out the compose section.

Means, if you want to do that then you follow below steps:

- Click on an ongoing email chain and press "reply" (or "reply all")
- By default the "reply" section will be inline; however you click on the left side menu with left arrow button
- It shows following options: "Reply to X", "Reply all" , "Forward", "Edit Subject", **"Pop out reply"**
- The last option will pop out a dialog box for the reply

When the other user, selected the "Pop out reply", this issue was happening. This could also be specific to the Mac's chrome browser.

Now that user has left the team, so cannot reproduce this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed that this one user is *just* hitting reply? I have one user who consistently breaks conversation threading, because he insists on modifying the subject by either changing it to the first sentence of his response, or by manually adding in the "Re:"  We've had conversations about this. I've at least got him to stop doing it to ME.

As another possibility, are they using the basic Google Mail interface to reply, or is it going through an app or outlook or something like that which might be interfering with the built-in process? Presumably, that could impact functionality, too.

**Note: see also @iammilind's suggestion about the possibility that they might be hitting the 'Pop Out Reply' option: if so, Chrome automatically adds a 'Re: ' prefix to the subject line (confirmed on Mac Chrome and Win7 Chrome just now. Good catch.**

Comment: According that user, others are not getting separate threads but only me. No subject line modifications and no external client for Gmail except modern chrome browser.

Comment: I'd check with the others yourself, if possible. The customer might always be right... but the user? Trust, but verify. ;)

Comment: You may want to refer my answer. The issue was with "reply all" by popping out in a separate dialog. The issue was specific to Macbook's chrome browser, it seems.